# If $|X|\leq c$ then $|\mathbb{E}(XY)|\leq c |\mathbb{E}(Y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, expected-value

Assume that $X,Y$ are two $L^2$ random variables such that there exists a deterministic constant $c>0$ with $|X|\leq c$  almost surely. Do we have the following inequality ? $$|\mathbb{E}(XY)|\leq c |\mathbb{E}(Y)|$$

Comment: If $X \sim \text{Uniform}[-1,1]$ and $Y = X$ with probability $1$, then $|\mathbb{E}(XY)| = |\mathbb{E}(X^2)| = \tfrac{1}{3}$ but $c|\mathbb{E}(Y)| = 0$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks alot for the counter-example !

Comment: I suspected you left out some conditions of the problem, but if not, then that counterexample should work.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 actually I want to bound $|\mathbb{E}(X_1 \cdots X_k)|$. I can bound $|\mathbb{E}(X_1|X_2,\ldots,X_k)| < c_1$, $|\mathbb{E}(X_2|X_3,\ldots,X_k) |< c_2$ etc $|\mathbb{E}(X_{k-1}|X_k) |< c_{k-1}$ but I can't find a way to bound the whole expectation of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \sim \text{Uniform}[-1,1]$ and $Y = X$ with probability $1$, then $|X| \le 1 =: c$ almost surely, but we have $|\mathbb{E}(XY)| = |\mathbb{E}(X^2)| = \tfrac{1}{3}$ and $c|\mathbb{E}(Y)| = 0$.